# Libboost 1.38.0 on Ubuntu 11.04 Natty

Tags: ubuntu, libboost

I have a Linux/Ubuntu DLL that depends on `libboost_thread-mt.so.1.38.0`.  I've tried various ways including building my own version of LibBoost 1.38.0 yet none of my methods have worked. I was wondering if 1.38.0 is available pre-compiled on earlier versions of Ubuntu or if my architecture (64 Bit) is not compatible with LibBoost. Does anyone have any pointers on how to fix this error?

Comment: This should probably be on Stackoverflow, but have you tried "boost1.38" or "libboost1.38" or similar?

Comment: Or try adding -dev as well. There should also be specific packages for the threading library, filesystem and what not, and one that includes everything.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you are trying to compile against a library on Linux or any other UNIX with `gcc` or various other compilers the following flags need to be set:

```
-L<location of the library> -l<library name>
```

`<location of the library>` could be `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib` or any other directory that library may be located in
`<library name>` is in your case: `boost_thread-mt`

If you are doing this on Ubuntu and you have installed boost 1.38.0 from packages there should be a corresponding `-dev` package that installs all things that you need to be able to compile your code with that library.